# Can we determine where the north and south magnetic poles are on stars and black holes?

Tags: black-hole, magnetic-field, pulsar

The question is related to this about [Are there collected data about the direction of rotation of black holes and the direction of the magnetic field?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13596/are-there-collected-data-about-the-direction-of-rotation-of-black-holes-and-the?noredirect=1#comment20105_13596). Perhaps it is observable for pulsars?