# How the magnetic field and the rotation of the planets and the sun inside our planetry system are related

Tags: rotation, magnetic-field, planetary-formation

Coming from this question [Are there collected data about the direction of rotation of black holes and the direction of the magnetic field?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/13596/are-there-collected-data-about-the-direction-of-rotation-of-black-holes-and-the) I want to know: How the magnetic field and the rotation of the planets and the sun inside our planetary system are related? Any tabellary overview is welcome.

Comment: They are not related and frequently change completely and independently. In the case of the Sun, every 10-11 years, in the case of the Earth, every few hundred thousand years.

Comment: @RobJeffries What is the actual situation of the planets of our sun system? How the rotations and the magnetic fields are related (right thumb rule for the rotations directions and north-south direction along the rotation axis, are they parallel or antiparallel?).

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field of the sun is generated by the Magnetohydrodynamic dynamo powered by the rotation of the conductive plasma that makes the sun. The details are not well understood. Similarly the magnetic field of the Earth is generated by the movement of the outer core. We have quite good models of the Earth's field now (including how it can flip), but it is not completely understood.

A non-rotating planet cannot sustain a substantial magnetic field.

Comment: Perhaps my expression was not good enough. Let me rephrase the question: Are actuel the North-South directions of the magnetic fields and the pseudo vectors of rotations (right thumb rule) of the planets and of the sun too all the same (parallel or anti-parallel)?